# Powershell: Force variable expansion

Tags: powershell

How can I force string variable expansion?

I need to read a string with one or more variable names in it (a template) and then expand it after I read the file. The key is that I must read the contents of the file before I declare the variables that will be used in the expansion. I've tried several ways but I can't get it to work.

It's not an option to read the file after $environment is defined.

Contents of name.txt: 
$environment-RPT-INT

```
#example 1
$name = gc "c:\temp\name.txt"
$environment = "9065DEV" 
$expanded = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($name)
$expanded

#example 2
$name = gc "c:\temp\name.txt"
$environment = "9065DEV" 
$expanded = $expanded = Invoke-Expression "`"$template`""
$expanded

#example 3
$name = gc "c:\temp\name.txt"
$environment = "9065DEV"
$name = $name.Clone()
$expanded = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($name)
$expanded
```

Any help is appreciated.

Updated: Example 1 is now working for me.

Comment: Hello there!  Are you saying $name contains the name of a variable that you want to get?  If so, you can use `Get-Variable -Name $Name -ValueOnly`.  If not, mind clarifying your desired goal with a little  pseudo code?

Comment: I'm using Powershell v2 and your first example works for me, what version are you using and what is your output?

Comment: $name contains the contents of the file c:\temp\name.txt, which I specify is the string: $environment-RPT-INT

Comment: I'm using Powershell 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you've found some possible solutions, but I'll suggest another that is in my opinion a bit smarter and more robust.

Instead of requiring variable names in your text file, why not use format specifiers.  For example, the contents of name.txt:

```
{0}-RPT-INT
```

And in your script:

```
$name = gc "c:\temp\name.txt"
$environment = "9065DEV" 
$expanded = $name -f $environment
$expanded
```

This way, you can rename the variable w/o changing any of your text files.  As a bonus, if your text file comes from unknown sources, your script is vulnerable to code injection.  For example, say you are given a text file with these contents:

```
$(rm -whatif -recurse -force c:\)-RPT-INT
```

Then ExpandString or Invoke-Expression will happily execute that code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Invoke-Expression` example is pretty close. Instead of using `$template` though, you need to use `$name`.

```
#example 2
$name = gc 'c:\temp\name.txt';
$environment = '9065DEV';
$expanded = Invoke-Expression -Command "`"$name`"";
$expanded;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called ExpandString predefined in powershell.  It's inside $ExecutionContext, as follows.

```
$mystring = @'
This is a here string with some embedded variables.

Here is variable foo -- $foo
Here is variable bar -- $bar
Here is variable bletch -- $bletch

'@

#This displays the here string as is.

$mystring

#now define foo, bar and bletch

$foo = 5
$bar = Get-Date
$bletch = "George Washington"

#now run the here string through Expandstring.

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($mystring)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to store your Setting/Values in a CSV, I wrote a module to pull values from a CSV, put it into a HereString... any variables you put into the CSV become fully expanded inside the Here-String.  That way, you can normally address the field names and values.

I might be able to change this to also work with traditional INI's if anyone is interested.

https://github.com/Inventologist?tab=repositories

Look for: HereStringFromCSV